# Get the token of a command name by means of another command

Tags: tex-core

There are two commands, one of which forms a token of kind "token-kind@number-of-section@number-of-this-kind-token". With that the name of token kind string and the corresponding counter name are passed as parameters to the this command. The second command produces a command name with the leading backslash and name itself coinciding with token of the same format, which is produced by the first command. Again, this command has two parameters of the same meaning as the first command. Now I define them as follows:

```
\def\commandNameToken#1#2{#1@\arabic{section}@\arabic{#2}}
\def\makeCommandName#1#2{\csname #1@\arabic{section}@\arabic{#2}\endcsname}
```

But the problem if I would like to change the format of the token, then I should change it in both commands \commandNameToken and \makeCommandName. However, I haven't won the TeX expansion mechanism in such a way that the command \makeCommandName uses the command \commandNameToken to get the token (to change the token format only in \commandNameToken).

Can any TeXpert advice the format of the command \makeCommandName referencing to the command \commandNameToken?   :)

Comment: `\def\makeCommandName#1#2{\csname\commandNameToken#1#2\endcsname}` should do the trick, since `\csname ... \endcsname` fully expands what is inside (after the first expansion step, you already have the same state as with your current definition of `\makeCommandName`). I'm not sure you use the word “token” properly, and not very clear about the usefulness of the first macro either. (?)

Comment: Actually, if you later redefine `\commandNameToken`, the `\makeCommandName` from my previous comment will use the definition of `\commandNameToken` that is current at the point where the `\csname` resulting from the expansion of `\makeCommandName` is expanded. If you want the definition of `\makeCommandName` to use a “snapshot” of the meaning of `\commandNameToken` when `\makeCommandName` is *defined,* you can use: `\edef\makeCommandName#1#2{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\expandafter\csname\commandNameToken#1#2\endcsname}}` (all this is untested because you provided no MWE).

Comment: Just complementing frougon's comments, you should add braces around `#1` and `#2` in case the arguments consist of more than one TeX token: `\def\makeCommandName#1#2{\csname\commandNameToken#1#2\endcsname}` or `\edef\makeCommandName#1#2{\unexpanded\expandafter{\expandafter\csname\commandNameToken#1#2\endcsname}}`.

Comment: @frougon most (if not all) TeX primitives whose argument is `<general text>` expand the tokens before the `{`, so you can use `\unexpanded\expandafter{<stuff to expand>}` saving you one `\expandafter` before the `\unexpanded`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik You are quite right, thanks! The forgotten braces are a stupid mistake... As for the unneeded `\expandafter` before `\unexpanded`, I “knew” about that but forgot to apply this still-fragile knowledge—I guess I haven't used it enough yet. I've incorporated your fine suggestions in the answer, of course.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed, I forgot about this feature of \csname. Expansion is, possibly, the last mechanism of the basic TeX, which I do not understand and do not feel intuitively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account Phelype Oleinik's fine comments, you can use:

```latex
\def\makeCommandName#1#2{\csname\commandNameToken{#1}{#2}\endcsname}
```

if you want `\makeCommandName` to rely on the meaning  `\commandNameToken` will have at the point where the `\csname` resulting from the expansion of `\makeCommandName` is expanded. On the other hand, if you want the definition of `\makeCommandName` to contain a “snapshot” of `\commandNameToken`'s meaning at the point where  `\makeCommandName` is defined, you can proceed as follows:

```latex
\edef\makeCommandName#1#2{%
  \unexpanded\expandafter{\expandafter\csname\commandNameToken{#1}{#2}\endcsname}%
}
```